# CI/CD with Github Workflow, Webpack, Playwright for e2e and deploy to dedicated server

Tags: webpack, continuous-integration, github-actions, single-page-application, playwright

We are setting up GitHub CI (Frontend) environment for our customer. I wonder if anyone faced the same problem with setup of a huge SPA project.

Frontend stack is: typescript, vuejs, webpack dev server (websockets and proxies for server api calls). We use Playwright for e2e and we are mocking all server calls there including websocket calls.
Server api is separated from the Frontend. Frontend part is rich on libraries, it takes avg 10 mins for a single build if not cached (200mb). So we need to minimise build runs hence they are slow.

Our current flow is dispatched on pull request:

1. Run eslint
2. Run unit tests
3. Modules install (with cache)
4. Webpack cache restore if any
5. Run playwright test on webpack dev server (we have proxies and websockets there), this helps to open connection to intercept api calls
6. Build artefacts and send it to our the standalone server.

Questions are:

1. Wouldn’t it make more sense to build SPA first to avoid extra build and serve build with some other http server and proxy server/websocket calls? If so how would you manage to run this build for e2e?
2. Is there any good way to make deployment previews for standalone server or serve it from GitHub? We are trying to avoid infrastructure grow and adding things like Vercel…

Thank you everyone

1. We have tried to build everything with webpack to stick with same library, but it takes 15-20 mins each run, which seems too long.
2. Run webpack dev server and take artefacts from there, but dist folder is getting cleared
3. Build with webpack and serve with http-server, but there are no websocket server and we will have to emulate or own, also proxy wasn’t working well for us.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't planning to answer this question myself but hence we found solution which fits best for us I will leave it here, may be someone will find it useful:

Our current workflow for our CI/CD is:

- PR from developer
- Run eslint
- Run unit tests
- Webpack builds production environment with compression and minimization and leaves it in /dist
- We take build to the artifacts (allows to pass to the next job and download it manually if necessary)
- E2E job run

  - Grab build from artifacts
  - We created small server based on node express server, specially to run previously compiled /dist

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws');


// Path to the dist folder
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, './dist');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);


// wssocket proxy
const websocketServer = new WebSocketServer({ server });

// Serving the files on the dist folder
app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR));

// service calls
app.get(/\/*(.svc)/, (req, res) => {
  res.json({});
});

// serve static files
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(DIST_DIR, 'index.html'));
});

server.listen(3000);
});
```

- npx playwright run ^
- Put reports to artifacts
- Deploy job